# Ошибка ajax скрипта в Firefox, который работает в Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, импорт, firefox-extension

Друзья, портирую расширение из Chrome на Firefox. У FF много своих особенностей с которыми нужно как то найти общий язык. Например, мне нужно отправить ajax запрос типа post, который в хроме работает, а в firefox не хочет, при чем не выдает никакой ошибки в консоле, просто доходит до этого куска и типа дальше ничего нет. Я новичок в веб-разработке, мой профиль десктоп C#.

Тестируется на Firefox Developer Edition 55.0b7 (64-біт).

Привожу код, который отказывается работать:

```
function getValues(callback) {
console.log('getvalues');    
browser.runtime.sendMessage({
        method: 'getParams'
    }, function(response) {
        callback(JSON.parse(response.data));
    });
}


function setPageData(extValues) {
console.log('SETPAGEDATA');
    var resumes = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
    var numberTypes = /\d+/;
    var idArray = new Array();
    if (document.getElementsByTagName('nav').length == 1) {
        console.log('if (document.getElementsByTagName(nav).length == 1)');
        return;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < resumes.length; i++) {
        var resume = resumes[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        if (resume !== undefined) {
console.log('        if (resume !== undefined)');
            var href = resume.getAttribute('href');
            if (href !== null) {
console.log('        if (resume !== undefined)');
                var id = resume.getAttribute('href').match(numberTypes);
                if (id !== null) {
console.log('    if (id !== null)');
                    idArray.push(id[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
console.log(extValues.webServicePath);
console.log(extValues.Login);
console.log(idArray);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
    asyns: false, 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=windows-1251',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: extValues.webServicePath,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            calcId: 'CANDIDATE.INWORKUA',
            args: JSON.stringify({
                form: {
                    ids: idArray,
                    userid: extValues.Login
                }
            }),
            ticket: ''
        }),
        success: function(data, event) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log('success');
            var valuesIn = JSON.parse(data.d);
            for (i = 0; i < resumes.length; i++) {
                var resume = resumes[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                currentId = 0;
                if (resume !== undefined) {
console.log('success');
                    if(resume.getAttribute('role') == 'button') {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(resume.getAttribute('id') == 'changeCat'){
                        continue;
                    }
                    var href = resume.getAttribute('href');
                    if (href !== null) {
                        var id = resume.getAttribute('href').match(numberTypes);
                        if (id !== null) {
                            currentId = id[0];

                        }
                    }
                }
                var node = resumes[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
                if (node == undefined) {
                    continue;
                }
                var parentSpan = document.createElement('span');
                parentSpan.className = extValues.lblId;
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                if (valuesIn.IN.indexOf(currentId) !== -1) {
                    span.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + extValues.ProfileColor + ';font-size:small');
                    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(extValues.ProfileIn));
console.log('if span.setAttribute, span.appendChild');
                } else {
                    span.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + extValues.AddColor + ';font-weight: bold;font-size:small');
                    span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(extValues.NotIn));
console.log('else span.setAttribute, span.appendChild');
                }
                var img = document.createElement('img');
console.log('image');
                //img.src = browser.extension.getURL(extValues.MainImage);
        img.setAttribute('src',browser.extension.getURL(extValues.MainImage));
console.log('img.src = browser.extension.getURL');
                var mainSpan = document.createElement('span');
                mainSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(extValues.lblId));
                mainSpan.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + extValues.MainColor + '; font-family:' + extValues.MainFont + ';font-weight: bold;font-size:medium');

                parentSpan.appendChild(span);
                parentSpan.appendChild(img);
                parentSpan.appendChild(mainSpan);
                parentSpan.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

                node.insertBefore(parentSpan, node.firstChild);
console.log('  node.insertBefore(parentSpan, node.firstChild);')
            }
        }

    });
}
getValues(setPageData);
console.log('getValues');
```

На моменте

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
```

прекраащается работоспособность. Но, если в консоле написать вот так

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=windows-1251',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'https://m.it.ua/ws/WebService.asmx/ExecuteEx',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            calcId: 'CANDIDATE.INWORKUA',
            args: JSON.stringify({
                form: {
                    ids: idArray
                }
            }),
            ticket: ''
        }),
        success: function(data) { console.log(data)},
  error: function(data) { console.log('nix_ne-ok-')}
   });
```

Запрос посылается и все отрабатывает. Кто сталкивался с подобным, помогите. Уже ума не приложу, что он хочет. Понимаю, что загвоздка в одном ньюансе, а найти его не могу, так как прошагать код в отладке (как я обычно в студии делаю) возможности нет, а Firebug никаких ошибок не выдает.

Заранее благодарен)

P.S: async : false не помогает.

Comment: В начале добавьте `console.log($)` и посмотрите что будет. Мне кажется jQuery у не подключен)

Comment: Попробовал, console.log($) -> выводит
function x()

Comment: А где вы это проделываете? Это ведь jQuery функция, а у вас расширение, подключение данного jQuery есть? Новая вкладка, консоль Firefox будет ругатся

Comment: А каким образом его подключить? в корне расширения есть файл jquery.js, оно где то явно должно подключаться? console.log($) добавлял после строчек function getValues(callback) {
console.log('getvalues'); выводит просто "function".

Comment: Я особо не силень в расширениях, заметил только что весь код на чистом JS без jQuery, и вы говорите что у вас на $.ajax ломается. Поэтому решил что он не подключается. Вам бы без jQuery всю эту радость реализовать))